# Валидация PHP AJAX.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Всем добра.
 У меня такой вопрос.
  Я делаю валидацию, пользователей.
   Более мене есть модальные окна, классы которые конектятся к базе, классы которые достают данные, и управляющие файлы.

Но я бы хотел добавить Ошибки. В поле формы :

При не существующием пользователе, при неправльном пароле.
   И что бы PHP отдавал JS эти ошибки. а JS вставлял их в форму если они есть.

***Я что не могу понять.***  Для принятия обработанных данных нужно

варианты ответа:

---

1. В файле JS который посылает данные в обработчик PHP. Создать новый AJAX в котором принять данные от сервера в sucess(function(data){if(data.response){записать ответ в переменную и дальше вставлять.})
2. Или в том же аякс запросе в **sucess** принять ответ от сервера?

---

В общем нужен совет, пример. Если что дополню вопорс кодом. Мне не совсем ясен алгоритм.

Comment: При ajax-запросах, сервер должен отдавать данные в формате json, а через ajax на фронт-энде уже парсить эти данные и выдавать пользователю результат. Еще есть вариант отдавать через сервер сразу html для рендеринга на стороне клиента, но используется это редко.

Comment: @Alexxosipov это понятно. Не понятно это должен быть новый ***AJAX***  или нужно принимать данные в AJAX запросе которые посылает данные?

Comment: ты оправляешь данные на валидацию, бэкэнд тебе возвращает данные в ajax, где ты отправлял данные. В том же, короче, в success

Comment: @Alexxosipov  А модальные окнна тоже, в sucess  открывать получается? И зкарывать?

Comment: смотря какие. Если ты авторизуешь пользователя, то после ответа от сервера, смотришь, success или error вернул сервер. Если success, то открываешь модалку, мол, вы авторизированы, если error, то выводишь уже error. зависит от сервера. Если ты делаешь и бэк, и фронт, то все в твоих руках, как захочешь, так и будет.